# active effect for multi li at the same time

Tags: css

I have a scenario that when I mouse down onto a li element and at the same time mouse move on other li element call css active for that.
like a piano that we press multi keys at the same time. and active effect show for all of them.

thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot track if a mouse button is pressed with CSS, JS is needed for that anyways. For example check [JQuery mouse events documenattion](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/).

Second, I believe "the piano-like" behavior means you need to press keys, not just put you fingers over it. And a mouse cursor makes you a "single-finger pianist". So, if I get your idea right (which I'm not sure), here is a simple JQuery snippet you may start with:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/uL5506xg/